# Not able to shift longtable to the left margin, it is coming in the center of the page

Tags: longtable

```
\begin{longtable}{ l l l } 
$\alpha$ &SiC polytype &alpha\\
$\beta$ &SiC polytype &Beta\\
Å &Bond Legth &Angstrom\\
I &Current &Ampere\\
U & Voltage &V\\
P &power &Watt\\
R & resistivity &ohm\\
$\rho$ & specific resistivity &ohm.mm\\
$^{\circ}C$ &temprature &centigrade\\
eV &bandgap energy &joule\\
$\Omega$ & resistivity &ohm\\
p &Pressure &bar\\
Mpa &presure &megapascal\\
Vol.\% &concentration &Volume percentage\\
D$_1$ & internal diameter &mm\\
D$_2$ & outer diameter &mm\\
t$_1$ & initial time &min\\
t$_1$ & final time &min\\
D &diameter &mm\\
L &length &mm\\
A &area &mm$^2$\\
v/v &concetration of a solution &volume per volume\\
M4 &thread size & 4 mm\\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: `\begin{longtable}[l]`

Answer (score 1):

longtable has an optional argument to control the alignment it defaults to `c` (centre) but here you want `l` for left.

```
\begin{longtable}[l]
```

Comment: can I add space between the columns as well? as the table is shifted to the left, it's more compact and not fitting to the page.

Comment: @divyeshk yes the column specification is identical to a standard `tabular`  you could for example locally pu `\setlength\tabcolsep{20pt}` to make columns further apart

Comment: Thank you very much @David Carlisle, you really solved one of my biggest problem.